# Eclipse CDT (4.5.1) works slow with pretty printing

Tags: c++, debugging, eclipse-cdt, pretty-print

I have a problem with huge nested data structures (from JSON Spirit). While debugging, when this structure is filled with data, Eclipse starts to work very slow, after every step it waits for printed data from GDB. The thing is that Eclipse gathers a lot of information about local variables even when I am not expanding this data structure. When pretty print is off, it works, but of course I can't see anything inside STL containers.

I am using printers from [GDB SVN](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/python/libstdcxx/)

Here is a little piece of code that can make similar problems:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>>> mega_map;

    const int factor = 50;
    for (int c = 0; c < factor; ++c){
        std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>> b_map;
        for (int b = 0; b < factor; ++b){
            std::map<std::string, std::string> a_map;
            for (int a = 0; a < factor; ++a){
                std::string a_str = "a";
                a_str += (std::to_string(a));
                auto a_pair = std::make_pair("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" + a_str, "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz");
                a_map.insert(a_pair);
            }
            std::string b_str = "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb";
            b_str += (std::to_string(b));
            b_map[b_str] = a_map;
        }
        std::string c_str = "cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc";
        c_str += (std::to_string(c));
        mega_map[c_str] = b_map;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Just make a brake at 'return', and you will see that it takes a lot of time to get something in 'Variables' window. During that time you can't debug.

There is a flag in GDB `set print elements number-of-elements` that can limit number of elements in containers to print, it works but while I am not interested in these nested structures, this settings affects other containers that I would like to inspect.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We (colleagues and I) hit and investigated this issue today, and here's our conclusion.  Unfortunately, we didn't find way to solve this problem using some settings only, but found some changes in CDT and GDB that could help alleviate it.  If you can build your own CDT or GDB it may help you.

CDT asks GDB for the locals using `-stack-list-locals`, with the argument to get their values as well.  For a pretty-printed container, GDB ends up including the children:

```
std::vector of length 20, capacity 20 = {<children here>}
```

For nested data structures, it can end up huge.  One fix is to make CDT not ask those values.  It will properly use variable objects and ask for the values as needed as you expand the data structures.  Here's the diff:

```
diff --git a/dsf-gdb/org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb/src/org/eclipse/cdt/dsf/mi/service/MIStack.java b/dsf-gdb/org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb/src/org/eclipse/cdt/dsf/mi/service/MIStack.java
index c319eb8..23bbb8a 100644
--- a/dsf-gdb/org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb/src/org/eclipse/cdt/dsf/mi/service/MIStack.java
+++ b/dsf-gdb/org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb/src/org/eclipse/cdt/dsf/mi/service/MIStack.java
@@ -859,7 +859,7 @@ implements IStack, ICachingService {
            fMICommandCache.execute(
                    // Don't ask for value when we are visualizing trace data, since some
                    // data will not be there, and the command will fail
-                   fCommandFactory.createMIStackListLocals(frameDmc, !fTraceVisualization),
+                   fCommandFactory.createMIStackListLocals(frameDmc, false),
                    new DataRequestMonitor<MIStackListLocalsInfo>(getExecutor(), rm) {
                        @Override
                        protected void handleSuccess() {
@@ -988,7 +988,7 @@ implements IStack, ICachingService {
                // the result without the values
                // Don't ask for value when we are visualizing trace data, since some
                // data will not be there, and the command will fail
-               fCommandFactory.createMIStackListLocals(frameDmc, !fTraceVisualization),
+               fCommandFactory.createMIStackListLocals(frameDmc, false),
                new DataRequestMonitor<MIStackListLocalsInfo>(getExecutor(), countingRm) {
                    @Override
                    protected void handleSuccess() {
```

There are other cases where CDT will issue requests that make GDB spit out the full recursive data structure, that is if you have the variable selected in the variables view or if you hover it.  Then you'll notice the full expanded value in the "Details" section.  But if you don't have that variable selected as you step, it steps quickly.

The possible fix in GDB is to not make it output pretty printed data structures recursively.  This hack for example limits them to one level of children:

```
diff --git a/gdb/python/py-prettyprint.c b/gdb/python/py-prettyprint.c
index 66929bf..b213699 100644
--- a/gdb/python/py-prettyprint.c
+++ b/gdb/python/py-prettyprint.c
@@ -700,7 +700,7 @@ gdbpy_apply_val_pretty_printer (const struct extension_language_defn *extlang,
   /* Print the section */
   print_result = print_string_repr (printer.get (), hint.get (), stream,
                    recurse, options, language, gdbarch);
-  if (print_result != string_repr_error)
+  if (print_result != string_repr_error && recurse == 0)
     print_children (printer.get (), hint.get (), stream, recurse, options,
            language, print_result == string_repr_none);
```

A contribution to upstream GDB could be considered where this recursion limit is a setting with a reasonnable value.

Comment: This looks very similar to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=519561 and I appreciate the analysis you have done. Can you add the same details to the bug please, especially if you believe it is the same. Thanks!